# Target of with statement does not bind to variable

Tags: python, contextmanager

I wrote the following code to manage a temporary directory.

```
class TempDirectory(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = None
    def __enter__(self):
        self.path = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        print self.path
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        def warn(function, path, excinfo):
            print "warning: could not remove temporary object '%s'"%path
        shutil.rmtree(self.path, True, warn)
```

However when I try to use it:

```
with TempDirectory() as tempdir:
    print tempdir
```

`tempdir` is always `None`. This is a problem, because then I can't access the path of the temporary directory!

I've poured over the [reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for the `with` statement in 2.7, and I can't see any significant difference between my code and the example presented [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/python_programming/python_ch27s03.html).

What's happening to my `TempDirectory` instance?

Comment: To be honest I can probably make do without a context-manager for this, but I really want to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Try returning something in `__enter__`. Perhaps returning `self.path` or something along that line.